# OpenCV SIFT detectAndCompute crashes without error on android

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, sift

I'm trying to implement some computer vision in an android app.

I have opencv integrated and I'm writing native c++ code for it that's called using JNI. That all seems to be working. My problem is that when executing the computer vision code the following line crashes the app without any error.

```
detector->detectAndCompute(usr_img,usr_mask,usr_keypoints,usr_descriptors);
```

If I use the orb detector, instead of sift it does work. On my physical device it then crashes on knnMatch. Whereas on an emulated Pixel 5 it completes correctly. Maybe it has something to do with my opencv and android versions?

Here's the full computer vision code:

```
void process_image(char* in_filepath,char* out_filepath){

   Mat usr_img = imread(in_filepath); //read images from the disk
   Mat ref_img = imread("redacted");
   Mat overlay_img = imread("redacted");
   Mat out_img;//make a copy for output
   usr_img.copyTo(out_img);

   //Set up feature detector
   Ptr<SIFT> detector = SIFT::create();
   //Ptr<ORB> detector = ORB::create(); //detectAndCompute works if I use this instead

   //Set up feature matcher
   Ptr<BFMatcher> matcher = BFMatcher::create(NORM_HAMMING,true);

   //generate mask for ref image (so features are not created from the background)
   Mat ref_mask; //defines parts of the ref image that will be searched for features.
   inRange(ref_img,Scalar(0.0,0.0,252.0),Scalar(2.0,2.0,255.0),ref_mask);
   bitwise_not(ref_mask,ref_mask);//invert the mask

   //and an all white mask for the usr image
   Mat usr_mask = Mat(usr_img.cols,usr_img.rows, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255.0));

   //detect keypoints
   std::vector<KeyPoint> ref_keypoints, usr_keypoints;
   Mat ref_descriptors, usr_descriptors;
   detector->detectAndCompute(ref_img,ref_mask,ref_keypoints,ref_descriptors);
   detector->detectAndCompute(usr_img,usr_mask,usr_keypoints,usr_descriptors);

   //match descriptors between images, each match is a vector of matches by decreasing "distance"
   std::vector<std::vector<DMatch>> matches;
   matcher->knnMatch(usr_descriptors,ref_descriptors,matches,2);

   //throw out bad matches
   std::vector<DMatch> good_matches;
   for(uint32_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++){
       //consider it a good match if the next best match is 33% worse
       if(matches[i][0].distance*1.33 < matches[i][1].distance){
           good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
       }
   }

   //visualize the matches for debugging purposes
   Mat draw_match_img;
   drawMatches(usr_img,usr_keypoints,ref_img,ref_keypoints,good_matches,draw_match_img);
   imwrite("redacted",draw_match_img);
}
```

My opencv version is **4.5.4**

My android version is **9** on the physical phone, and **11, api 30** on the emulated pixel 5

Comment: you cannot use NORM_HAMMING with SIFT. also: `Mat usr_mask = Mat(usr_img.rows, usr_img.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255.0));`

Comment: @berak Thanks, I've fixed those things, but the same issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

My images were 4000x3000px and approx 3000x1600. Scaling both of the images down by a factor of 2 causes everything to work properly.

I added a resize after each imread like this:

```
resize(x_img,x_img,Size(),0.5,0.5,INTER_CUBIC);
```

What this tells me is that SIFT in opencv 4.5.4 has a image size limit above which execution will crash without an error message. ..annoying.

It also explains why some of the detectors worked and some did not, and it even seemed to vary when I ran it on a real device vs an emulated one.